# I cannot see the points properly in the graph

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've marked three points on the graph but it seems I cannot see the complete graph and the points seems to be cut off. I've tried adjusting the dpi as well as figsize but nothing helps.

Graph:
[image]

```
# plotting KDE plot with descriptives
plt.figure(dpi = 256)
sns.kdeplot(churn_age, shade = True)
sns.scatterplot( [mean], [0], color='red', label='mean')
sns.scatterplot( [median], [0], color='green', label='median')
sns.lineplot( stdev, [0,0], color='black', label='standard 
deviation')
plt.xlabel("Age")
plt.ylabel('Density')
plt.title("KDE Plot with descriptives : Age of people who 
churned")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Just tweak the `ylim` a bit so that you can see a little below the kde...

Comment: Also, you don't need a scatter-plot for ploting a single point... just use `plt.plot`